# The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion using SQL Function

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created SQL Function for getting dates into my Gridview, So I am passing start date and end date to my Function but getting error like below.

`The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion`

If counts date greater than 100 means getting the above error, if below 100 dates means not getting any error. I have records of more than 100 days.

Below is my Data logic.

```
 public DataTable GetDates(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
  {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();// order by dt desc
    ConnectMethod();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select dt from dbo.ExplodeDates(@StartDate,@EndDate) order by dt desc", con);
    try
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", StartDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", EndDate);
        cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { return dt; }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I am getting this error on cmd.ExecuteScalar(); line.
Below is my SQL Function.

```
  CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ExplodeDates](
    @startdate datetime
    , @enddate datetime
   )
  RETURNS TABLE
  AS
  RETURN
    WITH DATES AS(
            SELECT @startdate AS dt
            UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEADD(D, 1, dt) FROM DATES WHERE DT<@enddate
    )
    SELECT * FROM DATES

     GO
```

Please help to out this Issue looking result since morning.

Comment: Just *don't* do that. Create a Calendar table with a large number of years. With only 365 rows per year, it takes no space but improves performance enormously

Comment: Already my site is on live please help to how to modify this code only or please update your answer. @Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: Check Aaron Bertrand's [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). 50 years of dates take 3MB. You could use the article's technique to avoid recursion, but calculate a date range when you can simply retrieve all the dates you want from a 3MB table?

Comment: No I dont want that much of years, only need 200 days for my application, can we do modify for 200 days for on my same above function, please help. @Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: Read the article, it already contains the scripts you need. Just create a table and *select* only 200 days

Comment: Btw: I'd understand to need some kind of *GetDateList()* function in SQL, but don't you think, this is much easier solved with C# directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the recursive CTE with a simple *tally-table-on-the-fly*:

```
DECLARE @NumberOfDays INT=200;
DECLARE @StartDate DATE=GETDATE();

WITH Numbers AS
(SELECT TOP (@NumberOfDays) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 AS Nmbr FROM master..spt_values)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,Nmbr,@StartDate)
FROM Numbers
```

`master..spt_values` should contain enough rows (~2500) to get sure 200 rows back. You can easily enlarge this number by using `CROSS JOIN master..spt_values AS v2`, which would allow quite huge numbers... (more than 6mio)

### UPDATE: a function

```
   CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ExplodeDates]
   (
      @startdate datetime
    , @enddate datetime
   )
  RETURNS TABLE
  AS
  RETURN
    WITH Numbers AS
    (SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY,@startdate,@enddate)+1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 AS Nmbr FROM master..spt_values)
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,Nmbr,@startdate) AS dt
    FROM Numbers;
  GO

  SELECT * FROM dbo.ExplodeDates({d'2017-03-01'},GETDATE());
```

Comment: Why do that each time instead of creating a calendar table once?

Comment: This I have to add into my function?. @Shnugo

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well, you are right and in my projects I do use a calendar table :-D But the OP told explicitly, that no physically stored table should be created - why ever... This approach is (almost) lightning fast... Fast enough for most needs. And btw: the `master..spt_values` is a physically stored table... :-D

Comment: PanagiotisKanavos I dont want for 50 years so only need dates for 200 days. @Shnugo

Comment: @mazhar124 You replace the code of your function with my code. You can replace `@NumberOfDays` with a simple `DATEDIFF()` with your `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`

Comment: @mazhar124 Just let the first `SELECT` start with `SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate)+1) ...`

Comment: You are not passing EndDate na. @Shnugo

Comment: I am confused, can update all answer please. @Shnugo

Comment: what is this mean: master..spt_values. @Shnugo

Comment: @mazhar124 The master database includes a table with many values, some kind of catalogue (just try `select * from master..spt_values`). I'm not interested in the values, it is just needed as a *filled* table... Using `ROW_NUMBER()` numbers these rows from 1 to n and this running number is the only value needed here... Any table with at least 200 rows could be used here...

Comment: I got answer because of you and stack over flow is running because of you people, Thank you very much, I have to give gift to you but how it posible thank you very much and you given exact Function code and ITs working to me. thank you once again. @Shnugo

Comment: @mazhar124 I'm glad to read this! Acceptance and (up-)votes are the way to say *Thank you* on StackOverflow. Everything fine here!

Comment: Why some body down my question and Its very interesting question and typical answer as you given. @Shnugo

Comment: @mazhar124 Never mind. On SO you must get used to down-votes. Voted it up as compensation... Just don't think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `maximum recursion` option after your select table. Like :

```
from DATES
option (maxrecursion 0)
```